# Intent in Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, layout, fragment

I got fragment app.But fragment_home.xml have a relative layout and have imageviews.I developed code snippet,but when I click on imageview,it is not runninng intents.image views need-

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    return rootView;
}
```

I write here for running intents via imageviews.because I looked java is not supporting multiple extend.like extends Fragment,Activity implements... etc.

```
 public class home extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton firstModule;
    ImageButton secondModule;
    ImageButton thirdModule;
    ImageButton fourModule;
    ImageButton fiveModule;
    ImageButton sx;
    ImageButton seven;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //init buttons
        firstModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        secondModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        thirdModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        fourModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
        fiveModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
        sx = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButto6);
        seven = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
        firstModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        secondModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        thirdModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        fourModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        fiveModule.setOnClickListener(this);
        sx.setOnClickListener(this);
        seven.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton1:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, MainActivitysld.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton2:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxx.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton3:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxx.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton4:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxxx.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton5:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxx.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButto6:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxx.class));
                break;
            case R.id.imageButton7:
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this, xxx.class));
                break;
        }

    }
```

edit:I added fragment_home.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/konu" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/nt" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButto6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ders" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/soru" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/cikmis" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ozel" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/strateji" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `xxx` are fragments or activity

Comment: just see good tutorial on fragment

Comment: xxx.classes names xxx.java

Comment: Classes in java should starts with upper case. Remember that. As a result, the code is clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is home.this?
What is your Fragment Activity?In startActivity you should give context of that activity and the class object..
Please cross check..and try with debugging,If your onclick method is getting called.
If not,set ImageButton.setclickable(true).
See if above options are working.

Comment: home.this is for intent.actually i did.i m seeing imageviews and silder menu i can changeing layouts on navigation drawer but when i came at first layout fragment_home do nothing click imageviews.

Comment: Is your on click method is working??
Try printing logs..and see if it is being called or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
firstModule = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
firstModule .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     startActivity(new Intent(home.this, MainActivitysld.class));
    }});

// for n numbers
```

Comment: where will i add this code in to public HomeFragment extends Fragment{}
or public home extends Activity implements OnClickListener ?